# How can I get Topic based on specific record in Salesforce

Tags: soql, topics

I am able to query on Topic object to get Feeds related to specific topic using below query.

```
SELECT Id FROM Topic WHERE Name = :topicName
```

In above query, how can I filter based on a specific record?

For example I want get only Account related feed based on Topic.

Answer (score 3):

What you need here is [TopicAssignment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_topicassignment.htm).

> Represents the assignment of a topic to a specific feed item, record, or file. This object is available in API version 28.0 and later.

So your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT EntityType,Topic.Name FROM TopicAssignment 
WHERE TopicId IN 
    (SELECT Id FROM Topic Where Name = :yourTopicName)
AND EntityType = 'Account'
```

Comment: Hi Jayant Das, Thank You For your reply. Feed Items are not coming for custom object. It is displaying by default under FeedItem object. While I have written like below, it is not coming is there any issue. Can you please fix this bug. SELECT EntityType,Topic.Name FROM TopicAssignment WHERE TopicId IN (SELECT Id FROM Topic Where Name = 'Pricing') AND EntityType = 'Competitor__c'

Comment: Few things - The forum is not intended to ask to "fix" any bug. The forum is intended to be able to help one wherever stuck. `FeedItem` contains posts, so if you are getting records there, that means that's a post of some kind. If you need to look for a Topic assigned to any object, the above query will just work fine.

Comment: That query is not working for me. I had data for my custom object chatter with topic, even it is not returning the result.

Comment: I can confirm this query works irrespective of standard or custom object as long as Topic is enabled for the object and that Topics are added on the record details for the respective object. If you are having some other issues, you may like to open a new question with the additional details. The best way to verify this is to add a Topic on a record and verify, and again I have verified this to be working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SELECT EntityType, EntityId, Topic.Name 
  FROM TopicAssignment 
 WHERE Topic.Name = 'Test' AND
       EntityId = '001...............'
```